# Swift check if two elements satisfy a combination of types

Tags: swift, generics

I want to check if two objects satisfy the condition that one of them is of one type, and the other is of another type. The order of the objects doesn't matter, only the Type combination. Is there a nice way to do this?

I've come up with this:

```
    if let shot = o0 as? ShotGameObject ?? o1 as? ShotGameObject,
       let o    = o0 as? TakeDamage     ?? o1 as? TakeDamage {

        o.takeDamage(shot.damage)

    }
```

Or this:

```
    for (o0, o1) in [(go0, go1), (go1, go0)] {
        switch (o0, o1) {
        case (let x as ShotGameObject, let y as TakeDamage):
            y.takeDamage(shot.damage)
        default: ()
        }
    }
```

The first one seems more efficient, but it's not pretty with the repetition and stuff.

The other one will generate overhead, by creating an unnecessary array, with two sets of tuples and a for loop.

Now there could potentially be a lot of different sets of combinations of two types which I want to check. Then writing many of statements like the first will be really ugly. The other would be nicer, but less efficient...

I tried to come up with a generic function to let me cast to a tuple of the types, but so far have not been able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic function to cast to a tuple of types

```
func tupleTypeChecker<T,U>(lhs: Any, rhs: Any) -> (T, U)? {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (lhs as T, rhs as U): return (lhs, rhs)
    case let (lhs as U, rhs as T): return (rhs, lhs)
    default: return nil
    }
}
```

sample usage:

```
if let pair:(Int, String) = tupleTypeChecker("hey", rhs: 1) {
    let b = pair.0 + 3//computes to 4
}
```